# How to insert xml as metadata into a image file (JP2 & TIFF)

Tags: xml, metadata, tiff, xmp

I am working on a metadata handling program, and I already have xml files and jp2 files right now. The goal is just to insert these xml files as metadata to jp2 files (throw all original metadata of the image away). But I didn't find (or don't know) any Java library I can use. Does anyone have idea that helps me? An example would help a lot!! Java or command-line tools would be great! I appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at libXMP it is a native library written in c/c++ and use native development kit NDK to compile and use it

Comment: Thank you for helping! But the other parts of program were built by Java, so I think a Java library would be needed.

Comment: You are welcomed. You can use a hybrid solution since you can mix java and native code together at least keep this in mind it may help you in the future ;)

Comment: I see! Thank you !